# How do I create a Haskell function like error (i.e. String -> a)

Tags: haskell, ffi

In Haskell, the `error` function has signature `String -> a`. It can return any type because it never actually returns. (It prints its argument and terminates the program.)

I've written a function in C that does something similar. It logs the string that is passed and terminates the process. Is there a way I can write a Haskell wrapper to have the same signature as `error`?

The C function has the form `void RaiseError(char* msg) { ... }`

So far, I have

```
foreign import capi safe "file.h RaiseError"
    c_RaiseError :: CString -> IO ()

raiseError :: String -> a
raiseError msg = unsafePerformIO $ do
    withCString msg c_RaiseError -- Does not return
    return (error "") -- Never gets called
```

There must be a more elegant way to do this.

Comment: Use `undefined`?

Comment: I wonder if you could do something like `foreign import capi safe "file.h RaiseError" c_RaiseError :: CString -> IO (Ptr a)`. Then you would still need `unsafePerformIO` but wouldn't need `error` in your `raiseError` implementation. I don't know whether the FFI lets you declare a polymorphic type like that, though.

Comment: I tried using `IO (Ptr a)`. It doesn't work because in order to deference the pointer (with `peek`), `a` needs to be `Storable`.

Comment: Ah, yes, of course. Then `error`, `undefined`, or one of the functions from `System.Exit` are your primary choices.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement a function of type `String -> a` in pure Haskell, but it won't have the same behavior as `error`:

```hs
error1 :: String -> a
error1 = error1
```

Calling `error1` will loop forever rather than printing the message and exiting.

The function [`Control.Exception.throw`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.1.0/docs/Control-Exception.html#v:throw) is similar to `error` in that it throws an exception without needing `IO`. You could use it to implement your own version of `error`:

```hs
import Control.Exception (ErrorCall(..), throw)

error2 :: String -> a
error2 msg = throw (ErrorCall msg)
```

Calling `error2` will be almost the same as calling `error`, except it won't have a call stack. (Call stacks are a relatively recent addition to `error`; see [`errorWithoutStackTrace`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:errorWithoutStackTrace).)

Ultimately you can't implement something like `error` in pure Haskell without relying on something like `throw`. `error` itself is implemented in terms of [`raise#`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/ghc-prim-0.8.0/docs/GHC-Prim.html#v:raise-35-), which is a primop. You can use the FFI, but you'll still have to rely on *other* primops like `unsafePerformIO` or `unsafeCoerce`.

This is the most elegant thing I could come up with:

```hs
import Foreign.C.String (CString, withCString)
import System.IO.Unsafe (unsafePerformIO)
import Unsafe.Coerce (unsafeCoerce)

foreign import ccall "file.h RaiseError"
    c_RaiseError :: CString -> IO ()

error3 :: String -> a
error3 = unsafeCoerce
    . unsafePerformIO
    . flip withCString c_RaiseError
```